# Не добавляется фото через форму на сайте Django

Tags: python, django, form

Пытаюсь загрузить фото через форму, но не загружается, через админку получается, а через сайт даже в папку не грузится с фото
models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    years_of_life = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Годы жизни')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class AddAuthors(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Author
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'photo', 'slug', 'years_of_life', 'biography']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'biography': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cows': 60, 'rows': 10})
        }
```

views.py:

```
def add_author(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddAuthors(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = AddAuthors()
    return render(request, 'book_app/add_author.html', context={'form': form})
```

html:

```
<h2>Добавление автора:</h2>
<form action="{% url 'add_author' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-error">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>

    {% for f in form %}
        <p><label class="form-label" for="{{f.id_for_label}}">{{f.label}}: </label>{{ f }}</p>
        <div class="form-errors"> {{ f.errors }} </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Пути MEDIA_ROOT и т.д. точно правильные иначе бы через админку не добавлялись фото.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: Я может чего-то плохо понимаю, но где у ваc input? У вас должен быть где-то <input type="file" ...> Кнопка button отправляет, но не грузит файл по идее

Answer (score 0):

Я слегка не внимателен, в add_author должно быть так:
form = AddAuthors(request.POST, request.FILES)
вместо:
form = AddAuthors(request.POST)
Я знал про это, но просто не заметил и добавил request.FILES не туда